# How do I send data via UDP from a device using a mobile hotspot to another device on my home network?

Tags: c#, python, tcp, udp

I am trying to send data from a Raspberry Pi 3B+ to my desktop PC back in my room. The RPi is connected to a mobile hotspot from my phone (Android), while my desktop PC is connected to my router (Frontier, D2200D) via Ethernet.

I was able to successfully send data from one device to another (via UDP and TCP) when they were on the same network, but it obviously doesn't work on different networks. I've done research on how to go about sending data over UDP from a device on one network to another device on a different network, but it's all very overwhelming. 
Does anyone have any recommendations for where to start my research?

Comment: It's not really the sort of Q we answer on SO so don't be surprised if your Q gets closed. As some pointers tho: your pc is on your home network, your phone is on the 4G cellular and is sharing that with the pi. Conceptually then your pi is "on the internet" via the cellular and must connect into your home network via home's public ip.Create a port forwarding on the router to forward Udp packets to your pc and then make the pi send packets to the publicly forwarded ip:port. Suggest reading up on udp port forwarding on your router, creating udp servers and udp clients. Check router firewall too

Comment: Also bear in mind that external forces like your cellular or broadband providers firewalls may block your attempts

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I agree this question is a little out of the ordinary. Thanks for answering though.